# why my localhost opening with a suspicious domain

Tags: apache2, localhost

When I type this domain: "geeker.com"

It opens my localhost, I'm unable to understand this. Even my host file (`/etc/hosts`) isn't using this name.

Have a look at this

[image: screenshot]

By the way, I'm using apache2 server.

Adding `dig geeker.com` results (suggested by @cocomac):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> geeker.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13460
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;geeker.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
geeker.com.     300 IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 308 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: بدھ جون 15 00:04:13 PKT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: What is the output of `dig geeker.com`?

Comment: @cocomac added the results.

Comment: Huh... so where it says `geeker.com ... A ... 127.0.0.1` , that means that there is an A record (domain to IPV4 address) in your DNS resolver that points geeker.com to localhost (127.0.0.1 is localhost). Can you add your hosts file (`cat /etc/hosts`)? Also, are you running a local DNS resolver, or are you using a standard public one like 8.8.8.8 (Google) or 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare)

Comment: @cocomac I double-check the file `/etc/hosts`, it's not there. But the site isn't opening after changing the internet connection, seems it was my previous net ISP who set that.